# Video tag loses aspect ratio briefly before returning to normal on first load

Tags: html, css, video

When my page first loads for a split second the video loses aspect ratio before returning to normal:

[image]

I am using the HTML video tag:

```
<video src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0533/4394/4904/files/Website_Home_Page_Video_1_1.mp4?v=1617166502" muted="" loop="" autoplay="" poster="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0533/4394/4904/files/amalfi-logo-black.png?v=1616983296"></video>
```

CSS:

```
.hero video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Source: https://amalfitiles.com/

Comment: It is your poster image flashing before the video plays, Can you just remove the poster? or try adding and adjusting the following:

`video{object-fit: fill;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I really like the website. The issue is that you have written your video element backwards, poster should go before so that it loads before the video.

```
<video controls poster=""//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0533/4394/4904/files/amalfi-logo-black.png?v=1616983296"">
    <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0533/4394/4904/files/Website_Home_Page_Video_1_1.mp4?v=1617166502" muted="" loop="" autoplay="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: No problem glad I could help